# bash script for git fetch and rebase

Tags: git, bash, key

I am trying to automate my interactions with Git by building a script.

I want to

1. connect with an amazon instance with .pem file
2. run the git commands from that ubuntu instance

I am a beginer in shell programming. I could give a try to do it like

```
#!/bin/bash
GIT_REPO='git_repo'
BRANCH='branch'
ssh -i ~/Downloads/4EBDBInstance.pem ubuntu@122.248.237.95
cd $GIT_REPO
git fetch -a
git checkout $BRANCH
git rebase origin/$BRANCH
```

I got an Error

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for '/PATH/Instance_key.pem' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: PATH/Instance_key.pem
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Actually I tried to implement the following Unix commands in a bash file

```
$sudo ssh -i PATH/instance_key.pem ubuntu@000.000.000.00
$cd git_repo
$git fetch -a
$git checkout master
$git rebase origin/master

(note:- need to inform with a message if any conflicts occurs and continue)

$sudo ssh -i PATH/instance_key.pem ubuntu@111.111.111.11
$cd git_repo
$git fetch -a
$git checkout release
$git rebase origin/release

(note:- need to inform with a message if any conflicts occurs)
```

Any help for implementing it

Comment: Shell assignments cannot have space around the equals sign. So `GIT_REPO = 'git_repo'` needs to be `GIT_REPO=git_repo` (the quotes aren't needed in this case either).

Comment: That error from ssh is exactly what it says. The permissions on `/PATH/Instance_key.pem` are too open. You need to fix them.

Comment: Fix the permissions of the key file, just like the warning says. Also, running `ssh` in a script followed by a bunch of commands does *not* mean running those commands on the server.

Comment: okay Reisne, how can i fix that error? Can I achieve what I want with that script?

Answer (score 2):

ssh will read its stdin for commands to run. You can use a heredoc:

```
ssh -i ~/Downloads/4EBDBInstance.pem ubuntu@122.248.237.95 <<END
cd $GIT_REPO
git fetch -a
git checkout $BRANCH
git rebase origin/$BRANCH
END
```

Comment: it does not help. Same error occuring after

"Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
The authenticity of host '122.248.238.32 (122.248.238.32)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 3d:77:2b:15:bf:99:4f:0b:03:6f:1d:ff:1a:54:7d:95.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? y
Please type 'yes' or 'no': yes
Warning: Permanently added '122.248.238.32' (RSA) to the list of known hosts."

Comment: Warning: Identity file ... not accessible: No such file or directory.
ssh: Could not resolve hostname /Users/faizalmohammed/Downloads/4EBDBInstance.pem: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Answer (score 2):

Give 400 permission to your amazon key, then try

```
GIT_REPO='git_repo'
BRANCH='branch'
ssh -i ~/Downloads/4EBDBInstance.pem ubuntu@122.248.237.95 "cd $GIT_REPO && git stash && git checkout $BRANCH && git fetch -a && git rebase origin/$BRANCH"
```

It will connect the instance and run those commands from there itself.